# Replace + with space character

Tags: javascript, regex

The original problem:

I send a JSON string with Unicode strings (many different languages and also md5 hashes) from a Java servlet to web clients. I URLEncoder.encode("my strings", "UTF-8") the strings before creating the JSON array.

(I'm almost sure something is wrong in this approach too, and I am probably doing one encoding too much though)

Anyway: 
in javascript I run a unescape() to get back the result, but spaces (encoded as +) are not decoded.

So I use `.replace(/\+/g,' ')` to replace + with space before calling unescape().

But:

leading and trailing + signs are omitted
and
consecutive + signs are replaced by a single space.

Please lend me a hand (or mind) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var string="+Salvis+Sumeet+Jacob,Srlawrjhkjh+"
var str=string.replace(/[+ ]+/g, " ");
console.log(str)
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HUC32/)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess

> leading and trailing + signs are omitted and consecutive + signs are replaced by a single space.

is what you want to achieve, not the outcome you currently get and want to avoid. If that's the case then

```
.replace(/\++/g,' ').trim()
```

will replace every one or more `+` characters with a single space, then remove leading/trailing space.

```
"++foo+bar++baz+".replace(/\++/g,' ').trim()
// "foo bar baz"
```

- [You may need String.prototype.trim polyfill for IE8 and older](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: `/\+/g` **WILL** take care of cases like `++`.

Comment: Sorry, but no, it's what I want to avoid. Please see my comments on the accepted answer. I'm sorry I can't upvote anything since it's a new accoutn.

Comment: But *if* the goal is to convert `++` to a single space it won't. I just assume that "consecutive + signs are replaced by a single space" is the goal, not the problem, as it wouldn't be a problem with current code posted in the question.

Comment: @user3873090 ok, your code should have worked as expected (`++` converted to two spaces and leading/trailing `+` left as leading/trailing space) so I thought it may be the goal, not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `unescape()` doesn't change `+` to spaces is because ... it's not part of its spec.

The ascii-space-character-as-plus-sign encoding is rather non-standard (though widely supported) and dates back to early versions of HTML.

Per the spec for [`unescape()`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-unescape-string) and [`escape()`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-escape-string), the only things that are changed by `unescape()` are hexadecimal escape sequences in the form `%XX` and `%uXXXX`. `escape()` replaces unicode characters outside a small subset of unrestricted characters with such hexadecimal escape sequences; `unescape()`, naturally, just reverses the operation.